# Maven: unresolvable build extension

Tags: maven, plugins, installation

I've been looking at google and nothing really points to this problem. When I run "mvn clean install" it returns the following error.

> [ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin
> org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:3.8 or one of its
> dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for
> org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:jar:3.8 ()

I'm trying to figure out how to import the maven plugin flexmojos but there are no clear directions on how to do this.

How would I import this plugin into my project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dependency you are looking for [does exist](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg:%22org.sonatype.flexmojos%22%20AND%20a:%22flexmojos-maven-plugin%22%20AND%20v:%223.8%22).
To troubleshoot this problem further we'd need to see your POM and the rest of your build output.

Taking a stab in the dark:

Is this the first time you're running this build on this machine? If so, a very common "gotcha" is a corporate firewall preventing access to Maven Central. The solution in this case is setup a Maven repository manager like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/), or configure Maven to [use a HTTP proxy](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I figured out that my working place has its own Maven dependencies for the project, so they were only available via LAN or VPN. therefore when it tried to fetch them, it returned saying it couldn't find it I believe.

Comment: @EjayTumacder ah, you mean there is a Maven repository at work? Yup, that's another possible scenario that would reproduce this error.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I set up the proxy in Eclipse then I discovered I also set up the proxy in my settings.xml. I deleted the proxy from settings.xml and all worked out.

I hope my situation will help!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding another profile parameter from my pom.xml to my mvn command, e.g. "-Pprofile-name" pointing to a non-Maven repo definition embedded inside that profile, since Maven might be looking for repo definitions to be standing alone in a settings.xml, which isn't always the case.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding a `settings.xml` file in the `~\.m2 directory`, with the appropriate configuration pointing to our internal libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If this Problem is displayed in the Eclipse Environment, this is because the m2e Connector tries to download the Plugins in to your `~\.m2\` repository

to solve this, open your Eclipse Settings: `Window->Preferences` and go to the `->Maven->User Settings` Section.
Check if either `Global Settings` or `User Settings` is connected to the `settings.xml` File that your Maven uses.

**Generally:** Maven or your m2e connector tries to download these plugins via the plugin-repositories configured in your settings.xml it's can't find them because the repository is unknown or not reachable because you are behind a proxy or so:

```
08.11.18, 15:54:47 MEZ: [WARN] Failed to build parent project for com.xxx.xxx.xxx:eclipse-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
08.11.18, 15:54:47 MEZ: [WARN] Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/sonatype-public-grid was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of tycho has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to tycho (http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/sonatype-public-grid): repository.sonatype.org
```

go to your `settings.xml` file and add:

Mirrors (in this example: `central` repository. Do so for any other repos accordingly e.g. `tycho`):

```
<mirror>
    <id>central</id>
    <name>Our mirror for central repo</name>
    <url>http://<your host to>/nexus/content/repositories/central/</url>
    <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
```

Repository:

```
<repository>
    <id>central</id>
    <url>http://<your host to>/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
    <releases> 
         <enabled>true</enabled>
         <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
         <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
    </releases>
</repository>
```

this should fix your problems:

**Eclipse Specific:** if Errors prevails (e.g. unknown packaging) add lifecycle mappings via `Window->Preferences->Maven->Discovery->Open Catalog` and add `Tycho Connector`
Further you can add the `lifecycle-mapping` plugin that handles these lifecycle mappings in the eclipse environment: [eclipse m2e lifecycle mappings](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you end up here because you are running nexus for a long time.
I finally found the error *Summary* tab in the *Repositories* page.
At some point *Maven Central* decided to require **https:** and the URL listed in my configuration still was using **http:**.

Update the URL to use **https:**, *Save* and everything worked smoothly again!