# Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, maven-3, tycho

I am using 'Tycho'(Maven) for eclipse plugin project build .

I am getting the error :

> > Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:0.22.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:jar:0.22.0: Could not transfer artifact org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:pom:0.22.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out -> [Help 2]

POM.xml file looks like

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">  
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>  
 <groupId>tycho_example</groupId>  
 <artifactId>com.codeandme.tycho.plugin</artifactId>  
 <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>  
 <packaging>pom</packaging>  

 <properties>  
  <tycho.version>0.22.0</tycho.version>  
 </properties>  

 <repositories>  
  <!-- add Mars repository to resolve dependencies -->  
  <repository>  
   <id>Mars</id>  
   <layout>p2</layout>  
   <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars/</url>  
  </repository>  
 </repositories>  

 <build>  
  <plugins>  
   <plugin>  
    <!-- enable tycho build extension -->  
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>  
    <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
    <version>${tycho.version}</version>  
    <extensions>true</extensions>  
   </plugin>  
  </plugins>  
 </build>  
</project>
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: No i am not using proxy

Comment: Well this is not normal since the artifact exists https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/eclipse/tycho/tycho-maven-plugin/0.22.0/. The error message is *connect timed out* which means that something is preventing Maven from downloading.

Comment: ok. Any way to debug this ?

Comment: I have the same problem when trying to build Eclipse Kura, but I am behind a proxy, so I'd say it's a bug about how Tycho manages proxy.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure your problem is solved. However, for others who have the same error,the solution is :
**Include the tag `<pluginManagement>` in parent pom.xml file.** `<pluginManagement>` is only a way to share the same plugin configuration across all your project modules.Here is sample parent pom.xml file

```
<build>
        <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>${tycho-groupid}</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>${tycho-groupid}</groupId>
                <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <resolver>p2</resolver>
                    <environments>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>macosx</os>
                            <ws>cocoa</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>linux</os>
                            <ws>gtk</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                    </environments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can't be solved by adding

```
<PluginManagement> 
   ... 
</PluginManagement>
```

It's simply because the eclipse m2e connector can't download these plugins from a repo.
Open your Maven Console and see if it prints something after you saved your `pom.xml`
it probably will tell you, that it couldn't acces the repo or no maven `settings.xml` is assigned to the m2e connector.

Find the full Solution here:
[Maven: unresolvable build extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53211196/8124631)